# Using np.ravel to specify yerr in errorbar plot

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, errorbar

My code generates values and corresponding standard deviations in sets of 3, i.e. 3x1 arrays. I want to plot them all together as a categorical errorbar plot. For specifying the yerr, since it only accepts scalar or (N,) or N x 2, I used np.ravel to convert all the 3x1 arrays to one single N x 1 array. But I still get the error ValueError: err must be [ scalar | N, Nx1 or 2xN array-like ]

Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
names_p=['p1','p1','p1','p2','p2','p2','p3','p3','p3','p4','p4','p4','p5','p5','p5','p6','p6','p6'] #### The names are repeated three times because for each variable I have three values 
y=(p1sdm2N_ratem,p2sdm2N_ratem,p3sdm2N_ratem,p4sdm2N_ratem,p5sdm2N_ratem,p6sdm2N_ratem) #### each of these 6 elements is 3 x 1 E.g. p1sdm2N_ratem=(0.04,0.02,0.03)

c=np.ravel((p1sdm2N_ratestd,p2sdm2N_ratestd,p3sdm2N_ratestd,p4sdm2N_ratestd,p5sdm2N_ratestd,p6sdm2N_ratestd)) ### each of these 6 elements is 3x1 e.g. p1sdm2N_ratestd=(0.001,0.003,0.001)

plt. errorbar(names_p,y,yerr=c)
```

This gives the error I mentioned before, even though c is an 18x1 array. (It's not an array of an array, I checked.)
Note, with the way I've set up my variables,

```
plt.scatter(names_p,y)
```

and

```
plt. errorbar(names_p,y,yerr=None)
```

work, but without the errorbars, of course.

I'd appreciate any help!

Comment: You might want to create a [mcve], i.e. a runnable code from which the problem becomes apparent. Else, I'd say better use a loop.

Comment: Figured it out! The problem was not in the yerr as the error message suggested, but rather in the dimensions of y. I used np.ravel on y and now it works.